# Does C++ ever optimize away pass by value for non-POD types?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

e.g., support you have a class with a constructor that reads in a vector by value:

```
class my_class {
public:
  my_class(const std::vector<int> _v) : v{_v} {}
private:
  std::vector<int> v;
};
```

Would there ever be a case where the compiler recognizes that it'd be better to pass by const-ref instead of by const-value and then decide to optimize it by adding a reference for you?

Comment: The only way to answer this is to use the compiler, and inspect the compiled output.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I see. Is it ever useful to pass by const value for a non-POD type?

Comment: It is useful if you wish to have your compiler enforce your self-imposed rule that your function cannot modify its passed in parameter. You will find that the best way to avoid bugs in complicated C++ code is to make them logically impossible. If it would be logically impossible for some particular error to occur if a function, method, or a constructor parameter is a `const` object, then it's certainly very useful to do so.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think maybe my question wasn't clear. My question in the comment was if it's ever useful to pass by const value instead of const reference for a non-POD type?

Comment: Sure. Everything that C++ offers is useful, depending on the circumstances. Passing by value, of course, effects a copy. So, if -- for whatever reason -- making a copy of an object, for a function's consumption is required then C++ being able to easily do that would, of course, be useful, and having the function parameter be `const` is also useful on its own merits, for the reasons that I explained. Rather than being concerned if X is "useful", it's more important to understand how everything works, then be able to make an intelligent decision if, in a particular situation, X is useful or not.

Comment: It should be `std::vector<int> _v` without `const` and `v{std::move(_v)}` and then there will never be a copy construction, only a move construction. Not only does that not require copying any allocation or elements of the vector, but it also makes it much easier for the compiler to optimize.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show the other thing you want to compare against more explicitly, and to clarify the title.  The trivial answer to the question you asked is that pass-by-value might still optimize away when inlining, if the compiler can prove that none of the work done by the copy-constructor was actually necessary in that case.